# How to remove comma before special character using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, angularjs

my string is like :-

```
var str = #805|6412,6413,#803|6392,6393,#802|6382,6383,6384,#96|622,623,#88|589,592,#810|6461,6462,6464
```

Now i want to remove comma before every (#) sign ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will replace the `,#` to a `#`. Removing `,`s before the `#` character.

```
var str = "#805|6412,6413,#803|6392,6393,#802|6382,6383,6384,#96|622,623,#88|589,592,#810|6461,6462,6464";
str = str.replace(/,#/g, '#');
```

Comment: That's it, Thanks ...! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Would you please accept my answer them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like

```js
var str = "#805|6412,6413,#803|6392,6393,#802|6382,6383,6384,#96|622,623,#88|589,592,#810|6461,6462,6464";

var newStr = str.replace(/,#/g, '');

alert(newStr);
```

or

```js
var str = "#805|6412,6413,#803|6392,6393,#802|6382,6383,6384,#96|622,623,#88|589,592,#810|6461,6462,6464";

var newStr = str.replace(/,#/g, '#');

alert(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace is your friend here. However this makes use of Javascript, not jquery.
So you'll make use of:

```
str = str.replace(/,#/g, '#');
```

We're making use of RegEx to find the replacements. The first parameter contains the RegEx expression to match, and the second contains your replacement text. Since we're looking for ",#' we replace it with # so that the hash is not also removed.

Breakdown of the RegEx... 
/,# indicates the pattern to match, the / really just identifies it as RegEx
/g indicates that you're doing a global replacement (global to the string, of course)

Have a look at these for more info: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp